# Can We Create Artificial Clouds In A Controlled Environment For Studying?

Tags: electricity, radiation, earth

I would like to know how clouds produce electricity. So, in order to do that, we must closely study clouds. If we can create artificial clouds in a controlled environment, it will shed us some light on how clouds produces electricity AND help prevent global warming by reflecting radiation from the Sun, thus making Earth cooler. Of course, I know the danger so I need to create artificial clouds in a controlled environment (indoors). Thank you!

Comment: Clouds are big. How are you going to build a building big enough to contain them?

Comment: I agree with @probably_someone - think of how tall a thunderhead is, reaching up to 40,000 feet or so. Convection cells in the atmosphere are big. Really big. And you need those to generate charge imbalances.

Comment: It isn't really the cloud that creates the voltage, it is the moving air in the updraft. Take a look at the Van deGraff generator to see how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We certainly can create artificial clouds, but the genesis of atmospheric electrical potential doesn't occur on the scale of a man-made laboratory.  See http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_09.html I'm sure there have been advances in the field since Feynman gave that lecture, but it still is a good place to start.